# Read binary code transmitted via radio in WAV recording

Tags: c#, audio, decode, wave

I have some WAV files that were recorded from a radio transmission. It contains information about who has send the transmission and I want to be able to read these information.
The information is transmitted by sending x hz for a 0 and y hz for a 1 ( More about [AFSK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency-shift_keying#Audio_FSK) on Wikipedia)

My problem is: How do I get the binary data out of the wave file? If there are controls for C# would be nice, but some source code for better understanding would be better.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://awesomegeekblog.blogspot.com/2009/04/file-transfer-over-sound-card.html

Answer (score 1):

The [WAV file specification](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/) is your blueprint for reading the sound data from the WAV file.  Sample code for reading and manipulating WAV files can be found [in this CodeProject article.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35725/C-WAV-file-class-audio-mixing-and-some-light-audio)

To achieve the tone mapping, you can [read this article](http://awesomegeekblog.blogspot.com/2009/04/file-transfer-over-sound-card.html), which describes how to write software to transfer data between two sound cards.  For example, to find out how much of a given frequency is present in a particular segment of the WAV file, you would use a Fourier Transform.

Something like this:

```
double fourier1(double x_in[], double n, int length) {

    double x_complex[2] = { 0, 0 };

    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < length; i++) 
    {
        x_complex[0] += x_in[i] * cos(M_PI * 2 * i * n / (double) length);
        x_complex[1] += x_in[i] * sin(M_PI * 2 * i * n / (double) length);
    }

    return sqrt(x_complex[0]*x_complex[0] + x_complex[1]*x_complex[1]) / (double) length; 
}
```

Where x_in is a se­ries of num­bers be­tween -1 and 1, and n is the mod­i­fied fre­quency:

`(length * fre­quency / rate)`

Comment: Thanks for the CodeProject link, at least I can now easy access the audio frames.

I need some help with the Fourier transform, though. I still don't get the x_in part. Where should I put the binary representation of the audio frame into? How do I incorporate the 1200 bauds my transmission is using?

Comment: FFT can't work, it is not a periodic signal.  Two bandpass filters are required.  There needs to be some kind of framing scheme as well to recover the data clock, similar to a serial port perhaps.

Comment: With two bandpass filters, you could just measure the "voltage level" of the output of each.  But according to the article, the FFT calculation accomplishes the same thing.  There's more code at the article.

Comment: I already read the article, but I still don't get the code, maybe because I don't understand the math behind FFT.

Comment: Can nobody help me out there?